# extract elasticsearch date from a <start-date>/<duration> XBRL-JSON format

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, arelle

I am storing XBRL JSON using elasticsearch.

[This xBRL-JSON OIM spec](http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/xbrl-json/PWD-2016-01-13/xbrl-json-PWD-2016-01-13.html#component-period-core-aspect) describes the `oim:period` property:

> Otherwise, an ISO 8601 time interval representing the {interval}
>   property, expressed in one of the following forms:
>
> <start>/<end>
>
> <start>/<duration>
>
> <duration>/<end>
>
> Where <start> and <end> are valid according to the xsd:dateTime datatype, and <duration> is valid according to xsd:duration.

Examples from [arelle's plugin](https://github.com/Arelle/Arelle/blob/master/arelle/plugin/saveLoadableOIM.py#L99) look like this:

- 2016-01-01T00:00:00/PT0S
- 2015-01-01T00:00:00/P1Y

I notice that arelle's plugin exclusively produces this format:

- <start>/<duration>

**My question**

**Is there a way to save at least the `<start>` part as a date type in elasticsearch?**

Ideas I had:

**elastichsearch only (my preference)**

- Use a **custom date format** which anticipates the `/<duration>` part, but ignores it

  - I haven't checked Joda yet; will it **ignore characters** in the date format if they aren't part of the special character? Like the "/" delimiter or the "P" which precedes any duration value (like `PT0S` and `P1Y` above)?
  - **EDIT** So the single-quote character escapes literals; this works `yyyy'/P'` will accept a value '2015/P'. However, the rest of the duration could be more dynamic
  - Re: dynamic; will Joda accept regex or wildcard character like "\d" or "+" qualifier so I can ignore *all* the possible variations following the `P`?
- Use a **character filter** to strip out the `/<duration>` part before saving only `<start>`as datetime. But I don't know if character filters happen *before* saving as type: date. If they don't, the '/`part isn't stripped, and I wouldn't be passing valid date strings.
- Don't use date type: Use a pattern **tokenizer** to split on `/`, and at least the two parts will be saved as separate tokens. Can't use date math, though.
- Use a **transformation**; although it seems like this is deprecated. I read about using `copy_to` instead, but that seems to **combine** terms, and I want to **break** this term apart
- Some sort of **plugin**? Maybe a plugin which will fully support this "interval" datatype described by the OIM spec... maybe a plugin which will store its separate parts...?

**change my application (I prefer to use elasticsearch-only techniques if possible)**

- I could edit this plugin or produce my own plugin which uses exclusively `<start>` and `<end>` parts, and saves both into **separate** fields;

  - But this breaks the OIM spec, which says they should be combined in a **single** field
  - Moreover it can be awkward to express an "instant" fact (with no duration; the `PT0S` examples above); I guess I just use the same value for `end` property as `start` property... Not more awkward than a 0-length duration (`PT0S`) I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but it's worth noting that the latest internal drafts of the xBRL-JSON specification have moved away from the the single-field representation.  Although the "/" separated notation is an ISO standard, tool support for it appears to be extremely poor, and so the working group has chosen to switch to separate fields for start and end dates.  I would expect Arelle support to follow suit in due course.

Comment: Thanks Paul. That would make my question moot. Other possibilities I considered since posting original question: 1) Use logstash and create a custom logstash filter, which allows me to transform the JSON how I want it.  2) Create custom elasticsearch type called `duration in time`, ala [attachments](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments), esp if I could specify semantics, like querying them (find all facts for a "quarter" (~3 months)). If I ever try one of those I'll let everyone know.

Comment: I see in the [latest spec](http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/xbrl-json/CR-2016-12-14/xbrl-json-CR-2016-12-14.html)  that we no longer use ISO 8601 format -- instead the `xbrl:startDate` and `xbrl:endDate` are separate JSON properties, and duration is inferred if both are present. So my use-case is moot, but maybe someone else will have similar question or answer (that is: parsing stuff out of custom text format for purpose of storing in elasticsearch, I should probably generalize question...)